# Is it possible to use socket.io.js with Jetty?

Tags: node.js, jetty, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io.js for the client to connect to a Jetty server with a Jetty WebSockets plugin.  It appears that socket.io.js is specifically designed to be used only with a node.js implementation.  Is it possible to configure socket.io.js with a server other than node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [Java implementation](https://github.com/tadglines/Socket.IO-Java) of a socket.io backend.

Alternatively, you could take a look at [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client), which is similar to socket.io, but is designed to support other backends than socket.io. [Including a Java one](https://github.com/purplefox/vert.x).